# Not able to get records(Spring repository) from DB using In Clause in Java

Tags: java, java-8, spring-repositories

This is my code. I'm trying to pull records from the DB (MySQL) using in clause, but unable to. Can any one let me know what mistake I'm doing

```
String multyStateCode= stateCodes.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")); // Output : 148,197

List<States> states= bbService.getStates(multyStateCode); --> This is calling repository class internally
```

My service class

```
@Override
public List<States> getStates(String stateCd) {
    pageable = PageRequest.of(0, Integer.valueOf(pageSize));
    Page<States> page = bbRepository.getStates(stateCd, pageable);
    return page.getContent();

}
```

My repository class

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM State c where c.stateCd in (?1)")
Page<State> getStates(String stateCd, Pageable pageable);
```

This doesn't return anything.

Note: If I pass only a single code i.e. 148 or 197 it returns value as expected.

Comment: @Hadi, It's getting passed in service layer

Comment: I think you query isn't correct. you should try like this. `Page<State> getByCodeIn(List<String> stateCd, Pageable pageable);`

Comment: Got it. Thank you